# Calculate Difference of each value of array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js, rethinkdb-javascript

I have the following data set. I have an array of objects like this

```
[{ 
    createdAt: Wed Feb 08 2017 12:16:35 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
    set: 'jr',
},{ 
    createdAt: Wed Feb 08 2017 12:18:36 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
    or: 'd',
},{ 
    createdAt: Wed Feb 08 2017 12:22:46 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
    or: 'd',
},]
```

I want to calculate the time difference between each `createdAt`, for example from 1st two `createdAt` fields it will give '2 minutes'.

Comment: show how should look the expected result

Comment: just  a  number   like  in minutes or  may  be seconds

Comment: Are you supposed to calculate the difference between each ? Between 1 and 2 - 2 and 3 - 1 and 3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly note that for this to work the date values need to be strings. Then you can use a simple `for` loop to iterate through the array, converting the strings to `Date` objects and comparing the current date value to that in the next array element. From there you can calculate the number of minutes between the dates. Try this:

```js
var data = [{
  createdAt: 'Wed Feb 08 2017 12:16:35 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)',
  set: 'jr'
}, {
  createdAt: 'Wed Feb 08 2017 12:18:36 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)',
  or: 'd'
}, {
  createdAt: 'Wed Feb 08 2017 12:22:46 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)',
  or: 'd'
}]

var differences = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
  var diff = new Date(data[i + 1].createdAt) - new Date(data[i].createdAt);
  var diffMins = new Date(diff).getMinutes();
  differences.push(diffMins);
}

console.log(differences);
```

Note that the above logic depends on the dates being ordered ascending.

Comment: well it  works  but  can  you tell me  that  how will i get   all values outside loop function  .  i think new array will be  required to push values in it  can  you   guide me

Comment: You could push it to an array - I added an example for you

Comment: thanks  i have done the  2nd part   .   the main problem i am  facing is  that  i   want  to  add  both of  these arrays  like  this  
` [{
  createdAt: 'Wed Feb 08 2017 12:16:35 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)',
  set: 'jr'
}, {
  createdAt: 'Wed Feb 08 2017 12:18:36 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)',
  or: 'd',
differnce,2
}, {
  createdAt: 'Wed Feb 08 2017 12:22:46 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)',
  or: 'd',
   differnce: 4
}]  `

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = new Date(arr[0].createdAt);
var b = new Date(arr[1].createdAt);
var diff;

if(a > b) {
    diff = a.getTime() - b.getTime();
} else {
    diff = b.getTime() - a.getTime();
}

diff = diff/1000;

// now diff is in seconds
// calculate minutes by dividing it by 60
// use this in for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

convert date to unix timestamp in seconds. then you can calculate the difference in seconds by arithmetic operation like below pseudo code.

```
var d1 = Date.parse('Wed Feb 08 2017 12:16:35 GMT+0500')/1000 //1486538195
var d2 = Date.parse('Wed Feb 08 2017 12:18:35 GMT+0500')/1000 //1486538315
var diff = Math.floor((d2 - d1)/60) + 'Min' + (d2-d1)%60 + 'Sec'
```

Similarly you can iterate over get each difference.